# Use a SELECT statement to find a parts of a sentence in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is a SELECT statement in SQL that when I want to search for a word if a sentence of more than one word is searched:

For Example, I have that material table:

- Olive oil
- Mineral water
- Rice
- Watermelon
- Fresh juice
- Mini wafer
- Mini milk

When I search for "Mi w" I want the following results to appear:

- Mineral water
- mini wafer

Comment: Do you want the same result for "w mi"?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will probably contain some product specific string functions.)

Comment: Using SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

```
select column_name from material where column_name LIKE 'Mi%[ ]w%';
```

Try using this, it would select all entries from the column you want which matches the pattern. Refer this for more info:-  [LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)